# byobu: "cannot exec new no such file or directory"

Tags: 12.04, byobu

I tried creating a new session in byobu:

```
byobu new -s gateway
```

Then I see this message on bottom of screen:

"cannot exec new no such file or directory"

and it returns this back to terminal:

```
[screen is terminating]
```

byobu appears to be up to date:

```
$ sudo apt-get install byobu
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
byobu is already the newest version.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there's a misunderstanding. You don't "create a new session in Byobu". Byobu is "only" a shell for a terminal multiplexer. As this terminal multiplexer as the backend to Byobu, you can choose between `screen` and `tmux`. You might say, running Byobu is more or less are way to run `screen` or `tmux` with added features.

Commands that you pass to `byobu` are passed to your backend. `new -s <sessionname>` seems to be a syntax that `tmux` understands, but not `screen`. It looks like you've configured Byobu to use `screen` as backend per default. You can choose the backend you want by calling `byobu-screen` or `byobu-tmux`, respectively, instead of simply `byobu`. Alternatively you can change your default backend with the tool `byobu-select-backend`.

So you've got two possibilities: Look up the syntax needed to have `screen` start a new session, or use `tmux` as your backend for Byobu as described above.